# Clustering large number of strings based on tags

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, clustering

I have string representations of text written by users in the form of parts of speech tags like so:

```
$NNDN,OVDANPN,PNVRV,^^V,^^!$^OV
```

and

```
 ^,G,#,!,N,R,$
```

etc. They are separated into two classes (0 or 1).

I want to be able to cluster these such that I will be able to predict (or try to) what class the user in from their tags using the damerau levenshtein distance.

The problem is that even a few hundred strings is a huge calculation for any basic clustering that I am aware of (but I am very new to this).

I've tried using the counts of each tag to form a vector but applying SVM, knn classifier and Naive Bayes yielded poor results, even when using a KS test to get the best features. My gut feeling is that this seems like a problem that could be solved in the same way that scientists would compare and cluster genes.

- Should I be looking at different machine learning methods?
- Is there another way of representing the strings that would be more appropriate?
- Is there another way of looking at the problem?

I'm using the scikit-learn library for Python.

Comment: What does the user's class represent?  It's possible that the classes simply aren't easily separable within the part-of-speech tag feature space.  While there are clustering techniques easily capable of handling a problem of this size, clustering seems like an unnecessary processing step if your end goal is binary 0/1 classification.  Also consider that frequency data often requires scaling or normalization before many supervised methods will be helpful.  Did you try that?  At the simplest representation, you might try tf-idf vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Levenshtein distance does not make a lot of sense in this context, as it is made for comparing distances between words.

A commonly used representation for texts is the bag-of-words representation, where a text is converted to a vector where every element in the vector represents the count of the corresponding word. In your case you could represent a text as a bag-of-tags.
The vector representation makes calculating distances a lot easier. However, I believe this is not necessary as you can classify the bags of words with Naive Bayes.

Once you have tried bag-of-words you can try more complicated representations like LDA, word2vec, and the like.